# Javascript .keyup() issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

http://puu.sh/3r1jk.png

I have that code and recently implemented the slider.  When the slider is moved it changes the win % as I want it to.  But if I was to enter it in the input i.e. 60% it would update multiplier and profit.  I want it to update multiplier and profit via the slider too.

Code to update inputs:

```
$(document).ready(functon() {
    function updateValues() {
        // Grab all the value just incase they're needed.
        var chance = $('#chance').val();
        var bet = $('#bet').val();
        var pay = $('#pay').val();
        var profit = $('#profit').val();

        // Calculate the new payout.
        pay = Math.floor((9900 / (parseFloat(chance) + 0.5)) * 100) / 10000;


        // Calculate the new profit.
        profit = bet * pay - bet;
        profit = profit.toFixed(6);

        $('#chance').val(chance);
        $('#bet').val(bet);
        $('#pay').val(pay);
        $('#profit').val(profit);
    }


    parseFloat($('#chance').keyup(updateValues));
    parseFloat($('#bet').keyup(updateValues));
    parseFloat($('#pay').keyup(updateValues));
    parseFloat($('#profit').keyup(updateValues));
});
```

Code to update win % via slider:

```
examples.push({

    range: [.01, 98],
    start: 49,
    handles: 1,
    connect: "lower",
    serialization: {
        to: [$(".exVal")]
    }

});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="form-box">
    <label for="bet">Bet Amount</label>
    <input type="text" name="bet" id="bet" class="text" placeholder="amount" />
</div>
<div class="form-box">
    <label for="pay">Multiplier</label>
    <input type="text" name="pay" id="pay" class="text" placeholder="Payout - 2x Default" />
</div>
<div class="form-box last">
    <label for="pay">Profit</label>
    <input type="text" name="profit" id="profit" class="text" placeholder="Profit" />
</div>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
<div class="form-box">
    <label for="chance">Win Chance (%)</label>
    <input type="text" name="chance" id="chance" class="text exVal" value="50" placeholder="Win % - 50.5% Default" />
</div>
<p>Slide to choose win chance or enter it in the input!</p>
<div class="noUiSlider" id="chance" style="margin: 25px 100px 10px 220px; colour:#00aec8;"></div>
```

Why won't it update?

Comment: Could you add the code in the image to your question? Could you also add your html?

Comment: Edited the OP.  HTML: http://puu.sh/3r1Mm.png

Comment: Because the slider just puts the value into the  `#chance.exVal`, but doesn't fire a `keyup` event - you will have to call `updateValues` manually. If you could show us what slider code you're using we might be able to help you with that.

Comment: My slider code in JS and HTML is in the OP.  Am I missing something?

Comment: You might want to create a custom event and link both inputs to that. Should make things easier to manage.

Comment: @WoLpH can you give me an example?

Comment: @user2534566: here's an example http://jsfiddle.net/kMGyr/

Comment: If you could implement it into my code that'd be helpful, but thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have typo in first line "functon" instead of "function".

Also change

```
parseFloat($('#chance').keyup(updateValues));
parseFloat($('#bet').keyup(updateValues));
parseFloat($('#pay').keyup(updateValues));
parseFloat($('#profit').keyup(updateValues));
```

to

```
$('#chance').keyup(updateValues);
$('#bet').keyup(updateValues);
$('#pay').keyup(updateValues);
$('#profit').keyup(updateValues);
```

**EDIT**

This slider has no events, so click event handler seems to by only option

```
$('.noUiSlider, .noUiSlider *').click(updateValues);
```

Comment: that typo isn't in my actual code (don't know how it got there).  Good catch but that's not the fix / issue.

Comment: you should provide more details about slider because I can't reproduce the issue without code

Comment: Yes, of course, so where is `examples` initialized? What does it refer to?

Comment: That comes from the source that I'm using to have the slider.  noUiSlider